# How to get FFMPEG -progress url data with php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG for Live-Streaming, I am using these parameters:

```
$start_command = DOCROOT.'bin/ffmpeg -y -nostdin -hide_banner -loglevel warning -err_detect ignore_err -user_agent "'.$user_agent.'" -nofix_dts -start_at_zero -copyts -vsync 0 -correct_ts_overflow 0 -avoid_negative_ts disabled -probesize '.$stream_probesize.' -analyzeduration '.$stream_analyze_duration.' -progress http://127.0.0.1:'.getbroadcastport($get_stream['stream_server_id']).'/_lib/lib.progress.php?stream_id='.$stream_id.' -i '.$stream_source.' -vcodec copy  -scodec copy -acodec copy -individual_header_trailer 0 -f segment -segment_format mpegts -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 6 -segment_format_options mpegts_flags=+initial_discontinuity:mpegts_copyts=1 -segment_list_type m3u8 -segment_list_flags +live+delete -segment_list '.DOCROOT.'streams/'.$stream_id.'_.m3u8 '.DOCROOT.'streams/'.$stream_id.'_%d.ts';
```

I'm looping `$_POST` variables in progress.php with foreach but dont get any results.

The header of the file is:

```
127.0.0.1:5255close*/*Lavf/57.62.100chunked
```

What can I do here to get the ffmpeg informations from progress URL?

My progress php looks like this:

```html
$req = '';
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
 $req .= $key.$value;
}
file_put_contents(DOCROOT.'streams/'.$_GET['stream_id'].'_progress.log', $req);
```

Answer (score -5):

An example of use progress whit URL like :

```
ffmpeg -progress http://127.0.0.1/progress.php -i ........
```